# Kubernetes web application - Error java.net.UnknownHostException: mysqldb-service: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: kubernetes

My jdbc URL is
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysqldb-service:3306/mydb", "user", "password");

I am getting a Communications link failure error. I logged in and checked the DB container and I am able to connect to the database but can't connect from the application.

java.net.UnknownHostException: mysqldb-service: Temporary failure in name resolution

Here are my deployment files -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: loginwebapp

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: loginwebapp-configmap
  namespace: loginwebapp
data:
  MYSQL_USER: dXNlcg==
  MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST: mysqldb-service
  MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
  namespace: loginwebapp
data:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: cGFzc3dvcmQ=

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysqldb-service
  namespace: loginwebapp
spec:
  selector:
    tier: backend
    type: db    
  ports:
      - port: 3306
  clusterIP: None    
        
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name:  mysql-loginwebapp-deployment
  namespace: loginwebapp
  labels:
    tier: backend
    type: db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: backend
      type: db
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: backend
        type: db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name:  mysql-loginwebapp
        image: xxxx
        restartPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
            
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef: 
              name: mysql-secret
              key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key:  MYSQL_PASSWORD    
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: loginwebapp-configmap
              key: MYSQL_DATABASE
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: loginwebapp-configmap
              key: MYSQL_USER

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: loginapp
  namespace: loginwebapp
spec:
  selector:
    tier: frontend
    type: webapp
  type: NodePort  
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30088

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name:  loginwebapp-deployment
  namespace: loginwebapp
  labels:
    tier: frontend
    type: webapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: frontend
      type: webapp
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: frontend
        type: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name:  loginwebapp
        image: xxxx
        restartPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            targetPort: 8080
```